TikZ: Two Arcs Through Same Point
I generated the following figure and I would like to add the red line.
However, I struggle to achieve this with the code I currently use as the line should be tangent to the z-axis and the x-axis at the origin (poorly drawn in the figure)...

CODE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \coordinate (D) at (0,0);
    \draw (D) [<-,>=stealth']  arc[start angle=90, end angle=150, radius=7 ] coordinate [pos=0.5] (O);
    \filldraw[black] (O) circle (2pt) node [left] {Origin};
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(135:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(45:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(315:2);
    \draw ([shift=(45:.4)] O) arc (45:135:.4);
    \filldraw ([shift=(90:.2)] O) circle (.4pt);
    \node at (0.75,0) {North};
    \node at (-5.05,0.58) {z};
    \node at (-1.95,0.59) {y};
    \node at (-1.95,-2.5) {x};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}


Look for tangent in tikz.dev .

Should y be tangent to the black arc? Does the red arc has any requirements? Does it need to end straight to the right?

You can solve the problem by drawing a circle, then shifting it perpendicularly to the x and z axes by its radius.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\centerline{
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \coordinate (D) at (0,0);
    \draw (D) [<-,>=stealth']  arc[start angle=90, end angle=150, radius=7 ] coordinate [pos=0.5] (O);
    \filldraw[black] (O) circle (2pt) node [left] {Origin};
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(135:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(45:2);
    \draw[->, >=stealth'] (O) -- ++(315:2);
    \draw ([shift=(45:.4)] O) arc (45:135:.4);
    \filldraw ([shift=(90:.2)] O) circle (.4pt);
    \node at (0.75,0) {North};
    \node at (-5.05,0.58) {z};
    \node at (-1.95,0.59) {y};
    \node at (-1.95,-2.5) {x};
    % added
    \coordinate (P) at ($(O) + (45:2)$); % (45:2) is perpendicular to the x and z axes
    \begin{scope}[shift=(P)]
    \draw[smooth,variable=\Vt,domain=90:300,-stealth'] plot ({2*cos(\Vt)},{2*sin(\Vt)});
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}



Right. But you should use or construct tangent first. Just extend the y-axis backwards to see my point.

@MS-SPO I tried reading that part of the manual, but had trouble implementing it. If the curve were more complicated, I would have used the decorations.markings library for its coordinate system. I'll try reading that section again and updating my answer. Thank you for the feedback :-)

@MS-SPO I've spent some time in the documentation, and cannot figure out how to construct an arc which is tangent to a line using that specific syntax. I can draw a line which is tangent to a circle, but that's it. You've got me curious about how to implement this, though I would usually default to decorations.markings. Would you mind posting a MWE with its usage? Sorry for pinging you so much, and if this is extra work for you. Best!

Once you have the tangent, e.g. by starting from the y-axis end point,you know the origin point. Now you can use Tikz perpendicular facilities. // However, as a geometric problem using tikz-euclide will probably be more efficient. And yes, you can mix it with Tikz.
